# (system vulnerability) Trying to simulate JavaScript injection into HTML templates

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-injection

I'd like to REPRODUCE a scenario where a 3rd party testing team injected a `<script>` tag into an HTML template on our front end. Then I want to add code to prevent this (i.e. front end `angular sanitize` or on the backend).

Normally, this `Html template` gets filled out dynamically, then sent to the server where it gets converted to a `PDF`.

In the case of the script inject, they were able to inject `document.write('failed')`, which affected the resulting PDF.

[image]

Here is a sample html template, where I attempt to inject a script. However, it has NO affect on the final Pdf.

I noticed in their injection script they're using on `onerror` routine. Perhaps that's what I need to do...

Using Postman, I will `Post` to a Url something like this:

```
    https: // myServer.myApp.com/TheReport/api/ireports/ConvertToPDF?sessionID=BLA-BLA&reportID=12868
```

```js
{
    "htmlString": "<!DOCTYPE html><head> <script> var req = new XMLHttpRequest();req.open(\"GET\", \"https://www.bob22334455.com/ThisIsNotAPage.html\");req.send();req.onerror = function(){document.write(\"FAILED\");}} <meta charset=\"utf-8\"><style>@page{margin:0}html,body{margin:0;color:black;background-color:white}.page{margin:0;overflow:hidden;position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;page-break-after:always}body.A3 .page{width:297mm;height:419mm}body.A3.landscape .page{width:420mm;height:296mm}body.A4 .page{width:210mm;height:260mm}body.A4.landscape .page{width:297mm;height:209mm}body.A5 .page{width:148mm;height:209mm}body.A5.landscape .page{width:210mm;height:147mm}.page.padding-10mm{padding:10mm}.page.padding-15mm{padding:15mm}.page.padding-20mm{padding:20mm}.page.padding-25mm{padding:25mm}img{max-height:100%;max-width:100%;left:50%;position:absolute;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}.print-toolbar{position:absolute;right:100px;top:30px;z-index:99}.form-control,table{background-color:white;color:black;display:inline-block;width:auto}input,textarea{border:1px solid black}@page{size:A4}</style></head><body class='A4'>\n</script> <div>WELCOME HOME #555.</div></body></html>",
    "reportParameters": null
}
```

The final PDF is as follows:
[image]

On the backend, that `html` string is passed to the `c#` method in `.net`

```js
public Stream ConvertHTMLStringToPDFStream(string htmlString, long uID, ref string ExceptionMsg)
        {
            string form = "";
            string subject = "";
            int formPos = htmlString.IndexOf("<h4>");
            if (formPos == -1)
            {
                formPos = htmlString.IndexOf("<h5>");
            }
            if (formPos != -1)
            {
                int formEndPos = htmlString.IndexOf("<", formPos + 4);
                form = htmlString.Substring(formPos, formEndPos - formPos + 4);
                subject = form.Substring(4, form.Length - 8);
            }
            Stream stream = null;
            try
            {
                htmlString = Regex.Replace(htmlString, @"<link[^>]*>", string.Empty);
                htmlString = Regex.Replace(htmlString, @"<style>[^<]*", string.Empty);
                htmlString = Regex.Replace(htmlString, @"</style>[^<]*", string.Empty);
                SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf converter = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();

                // set converter options
                SelectPdf.PdfPageSize pageSize = SelectPdf.PdfPageSize.Letter;
                converter.Options.PdfPageSize = pageSize;
                converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = SelectPdf.PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
                converter.Options.PdfDocumentInformation.Title = uID == 0 ? "Report" : $"Report ID: {Convert.ToString(uID)}";
                converter.Options.PdfDocumentInformation.Author = "My Company";
                converter.Options.PdfDocumentInformation.Subject = $"{subject}";
                //converter.Options.WebPageWidth = webPageWidth;
                //converter.Options.WebPageHeight = webPageHeight;

                // create a new pdf document converting an url
                SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString);
                stream = new MemoryStream(doc.Save());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionMsg = $"ConvertHTMLStringToPDFStream form: {form}: {ex.Message} inner: {ex.InnerException}";
            }
            return stream;
        }
```

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, what we really need is some example code of how you compose this PDF.

Comment: okay, that's happening on the back end. we're using https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter-for-net . I'll try and pull some specific code, thank you.

Comment: (Why) do you allow script tags in the html to be injected?

Comment: @SalmanA - a 3rd party testing team found that vulnerability. I would like to manually reproduce it, and then make code changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In your provided `htmlString`, there is a part of it written `<script req = new XMLHttpRequest()`, but I think should be `<script>var req = new XMLHttpRequest()`.

There is other typos in your `htmlString`:

- You have two opening tags `<script>`, but only closing one with `</script>`.
- You need change `window.onload=\function(){` to `window.onload=function(){`.

Comment: that's right, thank you. Some typos there.

Comment: That's was enough to fix it, @bob.mazzo? Or something also happens?

Comment: No sorry.  I am still NOT able to reproduce the "Failed" injection message into my PDF. I'm using Postman to send the request.

Comment: @bob.mazzo I just updated my answer with more insights.

Comment: thank you. I've also updated my post with a `req.onerror` that I'm attempting to trigger, as a result of the `req.open`. This is what they did in their original test, and I am trying to simulate that in my local envir.

Comment: Seems like your updated `htmlString` still have two opening tags `<script>` and `<script ...` but only one closing tag with `</script>`. Inside `<script></script>` you must only have Javascript code to make it work.

Comment: I cleaned that html code, but it could be that an extra `script` tag was still there. It's a bit difficult to format this html code due to the way they are passing the html string down to the backend...I'm Updating now, and retesting...thank you.